# WoW lua get GUID from character name

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to do this basically

```
x = UnitGUID(nameOfCharacter)
```

But it doesn't work. It works to get my own GUID using "player" such as

```
x = UnitGUID("player")
```

This is being used with the CHAT_MSG_WHISPER event which states it returns the sender GUID but it doesn't.

Any ideas or is it just not possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the other player in your party/raid? At least according to [Wowpedia](https://wow.gamepedia.com/UnitId#Others), you can only use the char names of group members as a UnitId.

Answer (score 1):

The unitGUID call requires a specified unitID type.

In your example nameOfCharacter is not a valid unitID type.

So in your case it would be;

```
local x = UnitGUID("target")
```

Here is a link to the [possible unitID's](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api_types.html#unitID) that you can use.

Comment: nameOfCharacter is a variable holding the name_of_the_character this is fine to use if that character is in your group. The group bit wasn't made obvious to me from the wowpedia pages.

Comment: Oh sweet I did not know that.   Thanks